# Why is the new operator used for collections in todomvc dependency example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, todomvc

I am reading through the todomvc Backbone [dependency example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples) and noticed that the 'new' operator is used to create new collections, however the views, models, and routers, return the object itself.

Why is the new operator required for collections?

**Collection**

```
/*global define */
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'backboneLocalstorage',
    'models/todo'
], function (_, Backbone, Store, Todo) {
'use strict';

var TodosCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // Reference to this collection's model.
    model: Todo,

    // Save all of the todo items under the `"todos"` namespace.
    localStorage: new Store('todos-backbone'),

    // Filter down the list of all todo items that are finished.
    completed: function () {
        return this.where({completed: true});
    },

    // Filter down the list to only todo items that are still not finished.
    remaining: function () {
        return this.where({completed: false});
    },

    // We keep the Todos in sequential order, despite being saved by unordered
    // GUID in the database. This generates the next order number for new items.
    nextOrder: function () {
        return this.length ? this.last().get('order') + 1 : 1;
    },

    // Todos are sorted by their original insertion order.
    comparator: 'order'
});

return new TodosCollection();
});
```

**Model**

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function (_, Backbone) {

'use strict';

var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
// Default attributes for the todo
// and ensure that each todo created has `title` and `completed` keys.
    defaults: {
          title: '',
          completed: false
     },

// Toggle the `completed` state of this todo item.
     toggle: function () {
         this.save({
         completed: !this.get('completed')
         });
     }
   });

return Todo;
});
```

Comment: please post the specific code.

Comment: I get 'TypeError: obj[implementation] is not a function' error if I just use 'return TodosCollection;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a module returns a `new Object()` it is considered a Singleton since caching would not allow the same module to get loaded again.

The collection object I'm assuming you are looking at is therefore a Singleton. It is already instantiated so you would not need to do that.

[This](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js/collections/todos.js) is the file I'm assuming you are questioning about.

Also, it isn't necessarily required it is just an architectural decision. [Here is a great article about exporting in modules](http://bites.goodeggs.com/posts/export-this/).

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense. I still don't completely understand why it doesn't work if the singleton pattern is not used in this case, but perhaps I need to just stare at it longer.